# Authentication issue using the QuickBooks Web Connector: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: soap, quickbooks, qbwc

I have a SOAP server to handle connections from the QuickBooks Web Connector. The first method it calls is "authenticate" which correctly returns the data it expects, however it's giving me the error

```
QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'm at a loss on this one and there doesn't seem to be a solution on the web. The error message doesn't really give me anything to go on.

If anyone has any idea where I can look for more information about this I'd be grateful.

Here is the WC error log for the issue:

```
20140215.17:15:32 UTC    : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20140215.17:15:32 UTC    : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20140215.17:15:32 UTC    : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdate() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
20140215.17:15:32 UTC    : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : QBWC1031: Update completed with some error. Application has been notified of the error accordingly. See QWCLog for further information.
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Password management - Started
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Password management - Ended
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Performing SCHEDULED UPDATE for application = PManager SOAP
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: PManager SOAP
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): PManager SOAP
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://[SNIP]/pmanager/soapserver.php
20140215.17:16:30 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20140215.17:16:31 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:<serverVersionRet="">
20140215.17:16:31 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application sent a null for server version. Allowing update operation.
20140215.17:16:31 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.1.0.30">
20140215.17:16:32 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:<clientVersionRet="">
20140215.17:16:32 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
20140215.17:16:32 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'PManager SOAP', username = '[SNIP]'
20140215.17:16:32 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="[SNIP]"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20140215.17:16:33 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
More info:
StackTrace =    at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = QBWebConnector
20140215.17:16:33 UTC    : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20140215.17:16:33 UTC    : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20140215.17:16:33 UTC    : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdate() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
20140215.17:16:33 UTC    : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : QBWC1031: Update completed with some error. Application has been notified of the error accordingly. See QWCLog for further information.
```

SOAP response being sent to WC:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:authenticateResponse xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
    <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]">
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string">8d51474324d94e25aa1e6670da584204</item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string">C:/Path/File.QBW</item>
    </return>
</ns1:authenticateResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Or the SOAP response you're returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have updated this sooner... The problem turned out to be the version number, I was trying to use an older version that didn't support some features. Changing the version in the call to the WC solved it.

Comment: which version number? Which call to the WC?

Comment: Hate to be a gravedigger, but please help steer the lost ships at sea

Comment: Not sure what you're asking?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little late, but in case it helps anyone else, I had a similar issue, and changing the style from 'RPC' to 'DocWrapped' in the QWC file fixed the issue.

UPDATE 5/2017:

The OP's issue was related to a version number mismatch, but I have had the same symptoms where the issue was related to a Style mismatch in the QWC config.  According to [QBWC_proguide](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBWC_proguide.pdf) the correct version will depend on the server setup, but valid options include: "Document" (which is the default), "DocWrapped", and "RPC".

For my Rails setup, either "Document" or "DocWrapped" worked.

After changing this config, remove and re-add the Web Connector app.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer... Can you expand on this a bit?